# C# Object Serialized using Newton.JSON is Empty

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am having trouble in serializing an Object using Newton.Json, when I used breakpoints to debug, I found my serialized object is empty while the object provided to serializer is intact.

I have attached the Screen Shots. [image: Object To Be Serialized Intact]

[image: Serialized Object Empty]

EDIT :
Here is the Class whose list I am trying to serialize.

```
class ArgumentGroup
{
    String argumentGroupName = "";
    String argumentDescription = "";
    int argumentCount = 0;
    List<Argument> argumentList = new List<Argument>();

    public ArgumentGroup(string argumentGroupName, string argumentDescription, int argumentCount, List<Argument> argumentList)
    {
        this.argumentGroupName = argumentGroupName;
        this.argumentDescription = argumentDescription;
        this.argumentCount = argumentCount;
        this.argumentList = argumentList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the class you are serializing?

Comment: @EylM I have updated with the code snippet.

Comment: add this:
 `var obj = new ExampleClass();
var jsons = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });`

Comment: There are no public properties to serialize in this object

Comment: Use public properties, not fields. Fields are implementation details, only *properties* are part of the class's interface. Serializers (all of them) work with properties. They can be configured to work with fields as well, even private fields, but they *shouldn't* unless there's a very important reason

Comment: This - `String argumentGroupName = "";` is *private*, and thus won't be serialized. Make it `public` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your fields public, because default NewtonSoft.Json will only serialize public members or 
for some reason you really don't want to make your fields public, you can use the JsonPropertyAttribute to allow them to be serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Public fields are a bad idea - fields are implementation details. Serializers are meant to serialize *properties*.

Comment: yes so that is why added "or for some reason you really don't want to make your fields public, you can use the JsonPropertyAttribute to allow them to be serialize and deserialize."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that public fields is a bad idea, but it *would* make them appear in the json.

Answer (score 0):

Does JsonProperty have each class property?

```
[JsonProperty("argumentGroupName")]
public string argumentGroupName { get; set; }
```

and import:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
```

Comment: There's no reason for `JsonPropert`, JSON.NET serializes all properties by default

Comment: JSON.NET serializes just the public properties by default, not all properties !!!!

Comment: You used a public property which means `JsonProperty` isn't needed